# CocoaPods syntax error

Tags: cocoapods

First time using Cocoapods and i can not figure out for the life of me where my syntax is wrong. I have searched my error message, turned off smart quotes, and still getting this error:

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
target 'Pop the Question' do
           ^. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.

here is my podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.2'
Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'Pop the Question' do
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' 
end

target 'Pop the QuestionTests' do

end

target 'Pop the QuestionUITests' do

end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had uncommented this line:

`Uncomment this line if you're using Swift`

so it should look like this:

```
#Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.2'
#Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'Pop the Question' do
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' 
end

target 'Pop the QuestionTests' do

end

target 'Pop the QuestionUITests' do

end
```

Comment: Thank you! should i be uncommenting the line below it since i am using Swift?

Comment: Yes, then you should uncomment this line: `use_frameworks!` :)

Comment: @aCertos If my answer was helpful to you, consider accepting the answer. Happy coding in Swift!